# How do I customize deserialize to prevent structs with empty fields？

Tags: serialization, rust

I implemented serialize to support non serialization when the field is empty.

**I get the following error report by running the code**:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("missing field `body`", line: 1, column: 30)', src/main.rs:58:60
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

```
use serde::{Serialize, Serializer, Deserialize, Deserializer};
use serde::ser::SerializeStruct;
use base64::{encode, decode};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Response {
    pub status: i32,
    pub message: ::std::string::String,
    pub body: ::std::vec::Vec<u8>,
}

impl Serialize for Response {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where
            S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut fields = 4usize;
        if self.message.is_empty() {
            fields -= 1;
        }
        if self.body.is_empty() {
            fields -= 1;
        }

        let mut r = serializer.serialize_struct("Response", fields)?;
        r.serialize_field("status", &self.status)?;

        if !self.message.is_empty() {
            r.serialize_field("message", &self.message)?;
        }

        if !self.body.is_empty() {
            let body = base64::encode(&self.body);
            r.serialize_field("body", &body)?;
        }

        r.end()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let msg = "hello".to_string();

    let respose = &mut Response {
        status: 0,
        message: "".to_string(),
        body: vec![],
    };
    println!("respose: {:?}", respose);
    let a1 = serde_json::to_vec(respose);
    println!("a1: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&a1.unwrap()));

    respose.message = msg;
    println!("respose: {:?}", respose);
    let a2 = serde_json::to_vec(respose);
    // println!("a2: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&a2.unwrap()));

    let a: Response = serde_json::from_slice(&a2.unwrap()).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: And it works just like you wrote it to, what's your question?

Comment: I want to customize and implement a serde::Deserialize. If the field is empty, it can be ignored. Like golang omitempty

Comment: Add `#[serde(default)]` to [the struct declaration](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#default) or to [the optional fields](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#default) so that `deserialize` will set them to their default value when they are missing.

Comment: Thanks, it's working.
Let me take a closer look at the serde documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in serialization but in deserialization. You can either change `body` to be an `Option<Vec<u8>>` and `message` as `Option<String>`. Otherwise you can add

```
#[serde(default)] // defaults to empty string
pub message: ::std::string::String,
#[serde(default)] // defaults to empty vec
pub body: ::std::vec::Vec<u8>,
```

If none of the solutions are good for you the only option remained is to write your custom deserializer